# How to update multiple rows at once from a View ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got a View that shows a table of Devices that are stored in my database, the database is made using inject. Now my goal is to update the Available boolean of multiple rows at the same time. As can be seen in the picture below

[image]

controller

```
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Results()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Statistics");
        }
```

view

```
@using CosyKangaroo.Controllers
@using CosyKangaroo.Data.CosyKangaroo
@using CosyKangaroo.Utils
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Menu";
}

<h1>Welcome to the Kicthen view</h1>
<h2>Menu</h2>

@inject CosyKangaroo.Data.ApplicationDbContext DbContext
 <form  asp-controller="Kitchen" asp-action="Results">

 <table style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ddd;  padding-top: 12px">
            <thead style="border: 1px solid black; ">
                <tr style=" padding: 8px; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px; text-align: center; background-color: #04AA6D;color: white;">
                    <th style="border: 1px solid black; " >ID</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid black; " >Name</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid black; ">Available</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="border: 1px solid black; ">
                @foreach(MenuItem item in DbContext.MenuItems)
                {
                    <tr style="border: 1px solid black; padding-left: 10px;">
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; ">
                           @item.Id
                        </td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding-left: 10px; ">
                            @item.Name
                        </td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding-left: 10px; align-items: center">

                           <input type="checkbox" checked="@(item.IsAvailable == true)" name="all_sizes">
                </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
 </table>

  &nbsp;&nbsp; 

 <input type="submit" value="Update" style="float: right; margin-top: 20px">
</form>
```

Comment: So you want to update the Available boolean of multiple rows in database when click update button?

Answer (score 0):

This is just quick untested example to get you started. (I suggest buying a good book to read)..  Note: I use the jquery library in the example.  It uses an ajax post call to pass the updates back to the server.

Update the checkbox with a data id and class.

```
    <input data-id="@item.Id" class="cb" type="checkbox" checked="@(item.IsAvailable == true)" name="all_sizes">
```

After clicking Save collect the ids and checks and then post to the server.

```
let updates = [];
$(".cb").each((index) => {
    let cb = $(this);
    updates.push(
        {
            id: cb.data("id"),
            checked: cb.is(":checked");
        });
});

$.post({
    url: Genesis.url('/ControllerName/Results'),
    data:
    {
        deviceUpdates:updates
    }
}).then(() =>
    alert("Update successful")
);
```

Create a new class on the server to store the answers and update your controller method to receive the list of answers.   Then save to the database.

```
public class DeviceUpdate
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Results(List<DeviceUpdate> deviceUpdates) 
{
    // save updates to db etc,,
    return Json(true);
}
```